# How to use my own python code with OpenVino and the Intel Neural Compute Stick 2

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, yolo, openvino

I have my own AI python code for object detection. It is currently working with spyder.
From a video.mp4 I detect object by calling YoloV3-tiny .cfg and .weights files. I also use the coco classes.txt file.

What I want to do is to make it run in OpenVino and working with the Intel Neural Compute Stick.
Is it possible ? And if it is, how could I do ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible and there is a sample showing how it can be done. Please check it out: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/demos/python_demos/object_detection_demo_yolov3_async/object_detection_demo_yolov3_async.py

There is also a page with the info how to run the sample:
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_python_demos_object_detection_demo_yolov3_async_README.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll take a look !